# Can I display tiny dots on polygon in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native-maps

I have a requirement to display the polygon on the Map as follows

[image]

Can anyone suggest me if there is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to display using react-native-svg elements inside Marker

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Marker} from "react-native-maps";
import Svg, { Circle, Rect } from "react-native-svg";

export default function SvgComponent(props) {
  const {
    coordinate,
    
  } = props;

  return (
    <Marker coordinate={coordinate} pinColor={pinColor}>
      <Svg height="10" width="20" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="blue" fill="green" />
      </Svg>
    </Marker>
  );
}
```